# Transparent theme color in chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Is it possible to somehow use a semi transparent theme color like this in chrome?

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)">
```

This produces a completely black color. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: don´t know if it works, but what about hex color codes? For example with #80FFFFF You get a half transparent white color. If You change the values at the beginning, the transparency changes, example: #20FFFFFF, its more transparent

Comment: Where do you want to apply this theme? Android or HTML ? if Android where of it ?

Comment: In a website running in chrome

Comment: @amann So why have you added Android tag?

Comment: Then why are you added android tag in your question?

Comment: Because I want it to be shown on an Android device running Google Chrome. As far as i know, this is not possible on iOS. I've removed the tag for clarification.

Comment: I think the android tag is valid since it's an android specific question. You don't get a theme color in any version of chrome other than android.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this in your styles.xml of your activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Apply the above theme to your activity in the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
..
</activity>
```

And you're done.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for a website in chrome.

Comment: @Morteza probably because he meant for a website in chrome _on android_.